# A Meteor-Friendly Spellchecker

Tags: meteor, spell-checking, hunspell

Is there a spellchecker that plays nice with Meteor? I'm looking for something open-source and that cooperates in a purely JS environment.

Comment: Any spell checker should work fine. Try placing the minified library file in `client/compatibility` & initializing it on your template's rendered callback

Comment: @Akshat, is there one that you recommend? Also, is client/compatibility a special directory? I hadn't heard of that used in a traditional Meteor structure before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `client` is special, but `compatibility` is not. Anything under `client` will be served only to the client. I’ve more often seen `client/lib` for external libraries that you want to send to the client; see https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files